# convert curl request in httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

how to convert below curl request in httparty

curl --noproxy localhost -k -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"adminpass"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"   https://localhost:8443/api/authentication

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

got it working

```
require "httparty"

options = 
{
    :http_proxyaddr => nil,
    :headers => {"Content-Type" => "application/json"},
    :verify => false,
    :body => {"username":"admin", "password":"adminpass"}.to_json
}
response = HTTParty.post('https://localhost:8443/api/authentication', options)

puts response.body
```